# Why does flow startup up soo many processes on the same ports?

Tags: flow-project

Whenever I start a simulation, several sumo simulators will be spawned on ports 51402 and 51403 over and over again. Why does this occur ? Is it a bug or is there something that I am not understanding ?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSmbq.png)

Comment: I can only see one of each there. Dot post pictures of text, or links to them. Post the text.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it with RLlib or in the SUMO examples? If in RLlib, it's because it parallelizes it by nature. If it's by SUMO, please post on the github and we will look into it!

Comment: RLlib examples. Thanks

Comment: To get rolling RLlib starts up by creating the envs a couple of times. So, it'll spawn a few SUMO instances before the experiments get started.